# WinAPI Wait on a pipe for reading data

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, wait, readfile

I am writing a program for reading from and writing to pipes.
I found out that by using PeekNamedPipe function I can get the
number of bytes which are ready to be read. But I have a question
How can I wait for coming data. Can I use WaitForSingleObject function
for waiting on a pipe to get data from other end of pipe.
regards,

Comment: What kind of wait do you need? If you do a normal read, it will already wait (block) until sufficient bytes are available.

Comment: I want to read the all available data (the number of bytes which is returned by PeekNamedPipe) and after that going to wait and after coming data do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [Overlapped I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or preferably use [Completion Routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
They are both asynchronous (non-blocking), but I prefer completion routines as you register a callback that gets called when there is data to read - no need to poll for data. Check out the links and build and run through the examples. It may take a little time to understand / implement, but you will be glad you took that time to do it right when it's working well :).

Comment: I prefer overlapped I/O. Usually in my pipe communication I have several events like shutdown, specific actions and the event for the overlapped I/O I use to wait for. Depending on the protocol I use I usually have a header. I read the header with overlapped I/O. When I have the header I read the trailing message block with a blocking ReadFile...

Comment: @xMRi: What you described can be done with Completion Routines, but easier in my opinion. Also, if you're using Overlapped I/O, why are you using a blocking call? Doesn't that defy the Overlapped approach?

Comment: The sender writes the complete message (incl. the header) into the pipe. After I have read the header (with a non blocking call), I know the length of the rest and can read it non-blocking.

Comment: @xMRi: Okay, I can see that may be advantageous if you're using a `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` pipe. As I mentioned in the answer, either is a good approach, the main point to take I guess is to use an asynchronous method, and choose an implementation that suits the specific design requirement.

Comment: I use this also with PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE.

Comment: @xMRi There is no guarantee that a pipe will flush **all** data. In the scenario above, your blocking call to read a message's body may really block. Also, performing synchronous I/O on an asynchronous handle can [fail in subtle ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/12/10358935.aspx).

Comment: 1. It is true that my be not all data has been flushed... But it will "arrive" in a the next ticks. Because I am reading my pipe and I have a sender-receiver there is nothing to do for my thread... I know that there is a message wafting.

Comment: 2. Also the Scenario you are pointing at doesn't match either. (Also I know about this problem). If have a pipe and a thread that handels the I/O between pipe-server and pipe client. It is a one to one relation. The handle is used for reading overlapped. When I receive at least the header of my message I decode the header and read the rest. No I/O will be performed in-between reading the header and the full rest of the message.