# Executing a system command that returns the output of that command

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, stdout

So I have this code that executes a system command and returns the output.

```
std::string ExecCmd(std::string command) {
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = _popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe) {
        return "popen failed!";
    }
    while (!feof(pipe)) {

        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }

    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

This code works really well, except for one part: Everytime this function is executed the command is executed in a seperate subprocess, so I do not have "context", which I really need.
Example:

```
std::cout << Control::ExecCmd("cd myfolder");
std::cout << Control::ExecCmd("cd");
```

this prints `C:\Users\spata\Desktop\`, not `C:\Users\spata\Desktop\myfolder` which it is supposed to. How do I make it so that I can execute commands in the same "context", while being able to retrieve the output? Keep in mind I cant just merge all the commands into one, they need to be executed separately, but in the same context. Happy new year everyone!

I tried to tinker with batch files, however that still didnt work, and batch files are inconvenient.

Comment: so how would I go about it?

Comment: `while (!feof(pipe))` is wrong. Make it `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pipe) != nullptr) result += buffer;`

Comment: It won't retain the context but it will also not do the unnecessary `feof` check. To keep the context, you could start a shell in a process and write to it via it's stdin and read its stdout.

Comment: I, understand, but how could one do that? Sorry for being inexperienced...

Comment: I would use boost::process. It makes it work as portably as possible afaik.

Comment: start cmd with redirected output and write commands via pipe when need. finally write `exit\r\n` command - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77736860/using-pipes-for-input-output-for-createprocess-readfile-blocks-program/77740478#77740478